# Handler & current time with video.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

I'm working on new skins for my video.js player. I already added un handler. Now, I want to add the current timer on it which has to follow the progress bar.

There are two prototypes: one for the handler and the other for the timer. How can I add the timer into the handler ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to just the currentTime, you can listen to the `timeupdate` event. Assuming you've got a reference to your player:

```
player.on('timeupdate', function() {
  // do whatever you want with the time update
});
```

That being said, if all you're working on is building a new skin, you're throwing away a lot of work already done for you by not simply styling elements that are already in place. `CurrentTimeDisplay` will already handle keeping the `vjs-current-time` class updated.

My suggestion would be to try and get as far as possible using nothing but CSS, then when you find yourself limited move on to JS. If you get to the point you need extra listeners, the [events documentation](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/api/vjs.Player.md#events) are going to be the first place you'll want to look.

Comment: Thank you Matt :). I've already found a way to do this. I've but the currentTime into the handle object which is itself in the seekBar.